# Perform the operation on the columns of dataframe by ignoring specific characters in r

Tags: r, special-characters

I have a problem with performing the operation in dataframe when there are some missing values in those columns of dataframe. My goal is just ignoring them (not to delete the row or column with the missing value) and perform the operation as normal.

Here is my dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Lunch","Lunch","Breakfast","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Snack","Snack","Lunch","Snack","Snack"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner","Snack")),
  total_bill_x = c("*",14.89,20.5,17.23,30.3,"*",20.7,32.3,25.4,14.5,13.7,14.2,15.7), total_bill_y= c(20.75,"*",18.52,"*",27.3,23.6,19.75,27.3,21.48,13.66,15.59,17.3,14.78)
)
```

I want to perform the operation like `sum(dat$total_bill_x)` `sum(dat$total_bill_y)`.

Comment: Sorry I confused. I am new to stackoverflow. Is that alright now?

Comment: it's okay.  thank you.  Have a great day.  I only wonder because i spent some time on it and if it doesn't have value for you

Comment: Okay thank you. You too. I just want some recommend when I want to plot with ggplot maybe 7 images together? Which function should I use?

Comment: I updated with `summarise/across`

Comment: I guess you have p1, p2, ... p7 plot objects?, then use `ggarrange`

Comment: yep I have f1,f2,..,f7 figures

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213567/discussion-between-ben10-and-akrun).

Comment: @akrun you can see my picture here: https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/tree/master#

Comment: Looks like your pictures are really big to be included in a single page

Comment: Yeah that is what I mean but in general Is there other way?no? I guessed I have tried many methods

Comment: can you post as a question wiith all the methods that you tried.  Somebody might have a solution for this

Comment: I post here and someone just propose the patchwork like you said: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710972/combine-several-ggplot-in-one-page-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are `factor`, which needs to be converted to `numeric`.  There are elements such as `*` which would become `NA` in the process and gives a friendly warning

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
       summarise_at(vars(starts_with('total')), ~ 
             sum(as.numeric(as.character(.)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

If we don't want the warnings, one option is to selectively remove those `*` elements before doing the `sum`

```
dat %>%
     summarise_at(vars(starts_with('total')), 
       ~ sum(as.numeric(as.character(.[.!= "*"]))))
#   total_bill_x total_bill_y
#1       219.42       220.03
```

---

or in `base R`

```
sapply(dat[-1], function(x) sum(as.numeric(as.character(x[x!= "*"]))))
# total_bill_x total_bill_y 
#    219.42       220.03
```

---

Or change the `*` to `NA`, convert to `numeric`, extract the column and `sum`

```
dat[-1] <- lapply(dat[-1], function(x) 
         as.numeric(replace(as.character(x), x == "*", NA)))

sum(dat$total_bill_x,  na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

If we want to do a group by operation, one option is to convert the `*` to `NA` with `na_if`(from `dplyr`), convert to `numeric` (`as.numeric`), grouped by 'time', get the `sum` of the column in `summarise` and create the 'pourcentage' column by dividing the 'total' with the `sum` of 'total'

```
dat %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('total')), ~ as.numeric(na_if(., "*"))) %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(total_bill_x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%   
    mutate(pourcentage=total/sum(total)*100) 
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  time      total pourcentage
#  <fct>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 Breakfast    16        20.8
#2 Lunch        17        22.1
#3 Dinner       21        27.3
#4 Snack        23        29.9
```

We can also do

```
dat %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with('total'), readr::parse_number)) %>%  
     summarise(across(starts_with('total'), 
             ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE), names = "total_{col}"))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213534/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-perform-the-operation-on-the-columns-of-dataframe).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `readr::parse_number`

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('total')), readr::parse_number) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('total')), sum, na.rm = TRUE)

#  total_bill_x total_bill_y
#1       219.42       220.03
```

To sum by group i.e `time`.

```
dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('total')), readr::parse_number) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('total')), sum, na.rm = TRUE)

#   time      total_bill_x total_bill_y
#  <fct>            <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 Breakfast         45.2         48.0
#2 Lunch             51.4         34.1
#3 Dinner            53           70.6
#4 Snack             69.8         67.2
```

Comment: If I want to sum on column total_bill_x and total_bill_y ? what should I do for this?

Comment: Do you mean to `sum` both the columns? You can just add `sum` in the end. `dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('total')), readr::parse_number) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('total')), sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
   sum`

Comment: How can I use another function involve to finally get for example ```x=sum(total_bill_x), y=sum(total_bill_y)```

Comment: Like this for example: ```coord<-dat%>%
group_by(total) %>%
summarise(
x = sum(total_bill_x),
y = sum(total_bill_y)
) %>% 
mutate(med_x = median(x),
med_y = median(y),
lab = case_when(x > med_x & y > med_y ~ as.character(Lbl_fam_met),TRUE ~ NA_character_))```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Can you explain? Do you want to apply multiple functions on the same column?

Comment: Yeah first I want to achieve ```x= sum(total_bill_x), y= sum(total_bill_y)``` and then I want to find median of its both like ```med_x= median(x), med_y=median(y)```. I got stuck with the combination.

Comment: You can add multiple functions in same `summarise_at` like : `summarise_at(vars(starts_with('total')), list(sum = ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE), median = ~median(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: How to apply with this? ```coord<-dat%>% group_by(total) %>% summarise( x = sum(total_bill_x), y = sum(total_bill_y) ) %>% mutate(med_x = median(x), med_y = median(y))```

Comment: You can do `summarise_at(vars(starts_with('total')), ~list(median(sum(., na.rm = TRUE))))` but `sum` returns a single number it doesn't make sense to take median of one number.

Comment: in fact, here I want sum apart not sum all column total_bill_x and column total_bill_y together