# Combine several ggplot in one page in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to know the way how I can plot all my images (7 images) of ggplot together in one page but I dont know which one is a good choice I have tried `ggdraw()` + `draw_plot()`, `grid` function and also `ggarrange` but it seems not work to me. for the images I have `7` images and I want to set 1 row with 2 columns for two images and the last one just set it to new row and just set it like the first image.

Any advice, help would be much appreciated

Comment: A page, as in A4 ? It very much depends how you actually produce your page. E.g., do you use latex? rmarkdown? sth else?

Comment: How to produced the page?

Answer (score 3):

If I've interpretted right, you could use the package *patchwork*

```
library(patchwork)

p <- ggplot(iris) + aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length) + geom_smooth()

(p + p) / (p + p) / (p + p) / p
```

This ends up looking like this:

[image]

You could then save that arranged image with an appropriate width/height to fit nicely on whatever document you are using.

EDIT: You can add labels like:

```
p + labs(subtitle = "A") + ((p + labs(subtitle = "B")) / (p + labs(subtitle = "C")))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: what is If I wanna set the label for first image like A,B,C...,G what should I add?

Comment: @Ben10. If this answers your question, accept it and post a new question.

Comment: Not yet corresponding to the thing I want :(

Comment: I've ammended my answer.